# Is it possible to resolve a symbol to its value before passing it to macro in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Say that I have the following array of keywords

```
(def keys [::description ::url ::mailing-list])
```

which I want to reuse in two specs; one for defining a map and one for defining optional arguments to a function.

```
(require '[clojure.spec :as spec])

(spec/def ::project-map
      (spec/keys :opt-un keys))

(spec/def ::project-args
      (spec/keys* :opt-un keys))
```

The problem is then that the `keys` and `keys*` get passed the quoted symbol `'keys` and not the resolved value held in the variable it's referring to.

So my question is: Is it possible to resolve the value of keys at read time like the common lisp `#.` reader macro, or does the macro have to be redefined to resolve the symbol if it gets a symbol instead of a list literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also wrap them in another macro, since macros are responsible for how their arguments are evaluated.

```
(defmacro def-both [name name* keys]
  `(do (s/def ~name (s/keys :opt-un ~keys))
       (s/def ~name* (s/keys* :opt-un ~keys))))

(user/def-both ::project-map ::project-args [::description ::url ::mailing-list])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a half-icky solution with `eval`:

```
(spec/def ::project-map
  (eval `(spec/keys :opt-un ~keys)))

(spec/def ::project-args
  (eval `(spec/keys* :opt-un ~keys)))
```

This was suggested by mpened on the clojurians slack.

Comment: Works well with clojure but unfortunately doesn't with clojurescript

Comment: Hmm, it is unfortunate that spec is so macro heavy.

Comment: Yea I did end up using a macro in the end. I wish I could have expanded that one symbol though without wrapping in a macro.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was trying to register a spec dynamically. I had trouble because I wasn't passing in literal keywords, so the solution was to eval the macro's args and then refer to those:

```
(def my-key ::this-is-a-test-key)

(defmacro define-spec [spec-key validator]
  (let [local-key (eval spec-key)]
    `(s/def ~local-key ~validator)))

(define-spec my-key int?)

;;testing it
(s/valid? my-key 123)
(s/valid? my-key "ASDASD")
```

It's also worth noting that in cljs, calling `define-spec` will return nils because cljs doesn't support macros.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could just do:

```
(spec/def ::project-map (spec/keys ::opt-un ~keys))
```

Might need to use qualitified namespaces (e.g. `::opt-un`)

```
spec/def
```

is already a macro ;)

Comment: I don't understand why this would work. Since `::opt-un` is a shorthand for `:my-namespace/op-un` it shouldn't match the named arg `:opt-un` any more than `:opt-un`. If we look at the assert which fails it checks that the values of the named arguments are qualified keywords, not the named arguments themselves. [EDIT]: It doesn't work. Look at what you get when you generate from the spec. `::opt-un` is simply ignored and that is why the contents of of ~keys isn't checked.